# is that possible to get data once and the perfrorm query on that instead of database in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is that possible to get data at once and then perform query on it instead of database. Because I am doing calculation for almost 500 customers. for while i need to run almost 100 queries for each customer in database with same pattern , that why i am asking that if I can get data at once and then perform query on that data instead of database. because each time for each customer increase mysql cpu consumption

What i am doing right now

```
foreach($customers as $customer)
{
 $customer_charge=  CustomerCharge::where('customer_id',$customer->id)->with('rate_charge')->with('chilled_rate_card')-->with('frozen_rate_card')->get()
$this->calculateConsignment($customer_charge);
}
```

I want to do like that

```
$customer_charge=  CustomerCharge::whereIn('customer_id',[array])->with('rate_charge')->with('chilled_rate_card')-->with('frozen_rate_card')->get()
```

`Now find() here customer charge form $customer_charge object instead of database`

Is that possible if yes then how?

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes*.

When you perform a query, Laravel returns to you an Eloquent Collection which allows on which you can still call the same methods to retrieve a specific data:

```
$customer_ids = $customers->pluck('id'); // Assuming $customers is an Eloquent Collection

$charges =  CustomerCharge::whereIn('customer_id', $customer_ids)
        ->with('rate_charge')
        ->with('chilled_rate_card')
        ->with('frozen_rate_card')
        ->get();

foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    $customer_charge =  $charges->where('customer_id', $customer->id)->first(); // querying the already retrieved $charges data, not the database
    $this->calculateConsignment($customer_charge);
}
```

Comment: I hope this query will not go to database again??

Comment: No. Only the query to retrieve all the charges is going to the database. In the loop, you are querying the already retrieved $charges data, not the database.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now can you can you please verify my concern. actually calculate consignment was calling 20000 times. and these 20000 times i wast quering from database. it means now only one query will go into database right?

Comment: Are you doing another query inside the `$this->calculateConsignment($customer_charge)` method??

Comment: I was doing on customer_charge thats why i asked this instead of doing query in database each time i can do it once .is that idea correct?

Comment: Yes. Now you are doing only one query. And that's great.